# Possible to alias a font family/weight?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

I'm working in a project where font families are defined inline style with weighting detail built into them, like `font-family: Inter_700Bold`

Is there a way to alias that in css/html where `font-family: Inter_700Bold` becomes `font-family: Inter,font-weight:700`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution could be to have a selector that targets elements by the inline style you mention, and apply the weight/actual font to them.

```css
[style*="font-family: Inter_700Bold"] {
  font-family: 'Inter_700';
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-family: Inter_700Bold;">has the font family</p>
<p style="text-transform: capitalize; font-family: Inter_700Bold;">has other styles as well</p>
<p>doesn't have the font family</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use some sort of dynamic aliases in html/css, you gonna need some kind of preprocessor for that.
But while defining a `@font-face`, you define a local page alias for the font:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'this_font_will_be_used_through_this_long_ugly_name';
  ...
}
.some_element{
  font-family: this_font_will_be_used_through_this_long_ugly_name;
}
```

Sure you will need all possible combinations defined as such the `@font-face` definitions.